# database issue - elgg social network platform

Tags: php, mysql, database, elgg

I am considering using elgg as the basis for the social network on a website (http://elgg.org/).

basically I'll install it as almost a separate site (on a subdomain e.g. social.mydomain.com).

Now the problem:
-I'm adding this to an existing site, so I do user registration through the site I have already made. This means I have a users table in my database.
-Elgg has a users table also (different name of course), as it comes with its own registration system. But i need it to read from mine.

The question:
How can I change the table the elgg reads users from (I'll add all the fields elgg needs to my users table)? I'v tried modifying it in a few places in the source code but it keeps saying fatal error. So where do I change the name of the table I want elgg to read the users from?

Any help is appreciated!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to copy your users' information into the correct fields of the Elgg database. The information on the fields is located here:

http://docs.elgg.org/master/en/design/database.html

If possible, then set your website to retrieve information from the Elgg database, rather than vice-versa.